# How does Thread.__init__(self) in a class work?

Tags: python, multithreading

So I found this code:

```
from threading import Thread
class Example(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run (self):
        print("It's working!")
Example().start()
```

And it prints "It's working!" using another thread, but how does this work? I can't find anything about Thread.__init__(self) in a class. Does it have something to do with superclasses?

Comment: Are you sure? Did you try again? Perhaps you made some other mistake. There is nothing special about what you did here. Did you perhaps create an `__init__` method and then *not* call `Thread.__init__`?

Comment: have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-thread-in-python/) (there are quite a few more available online).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `__init__` method is entirely redundant. You are in effect replacing `Thread.__init__()` with your own implementation, where your own implementation simply calls `Thread.__init__()`. If you removed it, nothing would change:

```
class Example(Thread):
    def run (self):
        print("It works!")
```

Your `Example.run()` method is simply called because you started the thread using the [`Thread.start()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start):

> `start()`
>   Start the thread’s activity.
>
> It must be called at most once per thread object. It arranges for the object’s `run()` method to be invoked in a separate thread of control.

Also see the [`Thread.run()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.run):

> `run()`
>   Method representing the thread’s activity.
>
> You may override this method in a subclass. The standard `run()` method invokes the callable object passed to the object’s constructor as the target argument, if any, with sequential and keyword arguments taken from the args and kwargs arguments, respectively.

Your `__init__` method had nothing to do with that.

Now, if you created a `__init__` method in a `Thread` subclass and then did *not* make sure `Thread.__init__` was called, then you prevented the class from setting important instance information, breaking instances:

```
>>> from threading import Thread
>>> class Example(Thread):
...     def run (self):
...         print("It works!")
... 
>>> Example().start()
It works!

>>> class BrokenExample(Thread):
...     def __init__(self):
...         # not doing anything
...         pass
...     def run (self):
...         print("It works!")
... 
>>> BrokenExample().start()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 737, in start
    raise RuntimeError("thread.__init__() not called")
RuntimeError: thread.__init__() not called
```

Because this is a common error to make, the `Thread.start` method throws a custom exception to tell you explicitly that `Thread.__init__` was not executed.

Comment: Thanks! So basically, the Thread in Example(Thread) already initializes a thread? And how does the Thread class know what function to run?

Comment: @MorrisCasper: the `Thread` class provides all the functionality, you only need to provide a `run()` method. That's documented, calling `.start()` will create a new thread that then runs the `run` method.

Comment: What would happen if you made a start function inside the example class?

Comment: @MorrisCasper: you'd be overriding the `Thread.start()` method, and if you didn't then call the original the thread wouldn't be started and `run` wouldn't be called.

Comment: @MartijnPieters
Hi, Can you expand on this portion:
`and then did not make sure Thread.__init__ was called, then you prevented the class from setting important instance information, breaking instances`

Do you mean the keyword arguments with default values such as these:

`self.__ident = None
        self.__started = Event()
        self.__stopped = False
        self.__block = Condition(Lock())
        self.__initialized = True`

Which aren't called in the constructor?

Comment: @Moondra: you already found the `Thread.__init__` implementation then. I'm not sure what there is to expand here? The class is designed to have `run()` implemented in a subclass, and not `__init__`, or if you do implement an `__init__` method, then it is a bug not to make sure `Thread.__init__` is *also* called. Because that's a common error to make, `Thread.start()` verifies that certain conditions are met. It isn't important what exactly `Thread.__init__` does, that's all just an implementation detail.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry I think I was not clear with my confusion. I am confused as to why `Thread.__init__` also needs to be called in the subclass if you change the `__init__` method.  I am still a beginner to OOP in Python, but most examples I have seen in inheritance, the parent class `__init__` is usually called with some arguments because they want to inherit those specific arguments. However in the threading cases, `Thread.__init__` is called in the subclass `__init__` without any specific arguments, so I wonder why `Thread.__init__` needs to be called within the parent `__init__` at all

Answer (score 2):

`__init__()` method is called when an object is initialized. And when you do - `Thread.__init__(self)` , it just just calling the parent class' `__init__()` method .

Like said in comment you can remove it and the functionality should remain same. In your class the `__init__()` is completely redundant.

This method is called when you do -

```
Example()
```

When you create the new object for `Example()` .

The `run()` method is called, when you do - `.start()` on the `Example()` object. This is done by the [`Thread.start()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) method, from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) -

> **start()**
>
> Start the thread’s activity.
>
> It must be called at most once per thread object. It arranges for the object’s run() method to be invoked in a separate thread of control.

---

Adding one more print statement and dividing `Example().start()` into two lines so you can understand this clearly -

```
>>> from threading import Thread
>>> class Example(Thread):
...     def __init__(self):
...         Thread.__init__(self)
...         print("In __init__")
...     def run (self):
...         print("It's working!")
...
>>> e = Example()
In __init__
>>> e.start()
It's working!
```