# Why the need for Thread.__init__() in a Class?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

Why am I forced to use `threading.Thread.__init__(self)` or `super(ClassName, self).__init__()` when I create a `threading.Thread` Class?

For example:

```
class Threader(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, _fp, _q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.path = _fp
        self.queue = _q

    def run(self):
        # Do stuff
```

or

```
class Threader(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, _fp, _q):
        super(Threader, self).__init__()
        self.path = _fp
        self.queue = _q

    def run(self):
        # Do stuff
```

Both methods work, and do roughly the same thing. However, if I remove either `.__init__()` methods, I receive in the stack: `from thread.start(): thread.__init__() not called`.

Shouldn't defining my own `def __init__()` "replace" the `.__init__()` method?

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851514/how-does-thread-init-self-in-a-class-work) other SO post and that aligned with what I thought, get same stack error though.

Comment: Why refine the `Thread` class at all?  Why not just instantiate a `Thread` and give it a callable delegate? `my_thread=threading.Thread(target=my_callable)`

Comment: @jameslarge Syntax is just cleaner for what we are doing with the GUI updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this simplified example:

```
class dog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.legs = 4
        self.sound = 'woof'

class chihuahua(dog):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sound = 'yip'
        # what's missing here?
```

We've created a subclass of `dog`, called `chihuahua`.  A user of this class would reasonably expect it to behave like a dog in all default aspects, except the specific one that we have overridden (the sound it makes).   But note that, as you have pointed out, the new subclass `__init__` replaces the base class `__init__`.  *Completely* replaces. Unlike C++, the base-class initialization code is *not* automatically called when a subclass instance is created.  Therefore, the line `self.legs = 4` never gets run when you create a `chihuahua()`.  As a result, this type of dog is running around without any idea how many legs it has. Hence you could argue it is not a fully-functioning dog, and you shouldn't be surprised if it falls over while trying to perform complex tricks.

As subclass designer you have two options to fix this. The first is to reimplement the `self.legs = 4` line explicitly in the subclass. Well, that'll work fine in this example, but it's not a great option in general because it violates the DRY principle even in cases where you *do* know exactly what code to write and how to maintain it. And in more complex examples (like your `Thread` subclass), you presumably *won't* know. Second option: explicitly call the superclass initializer and let it do its thing.

Answer (score 1):

Defining your own `__init__` overrides the base class. But what about all the work the base `__init__` does to make the thread runnable? All variables and state that it would normally create are missing. Unless you hack all of that in yourself (and why do that?) the thread is of course completely unrunnable.

Not all classes need an `__init__` of course, but the vast majority do. Even for the ones that don't, calling `__init__` is harmless - it just goes to `object.__init__` and future-proofs the child class in the event an implementer decides an `__init__` is useful after all.